# How to test my ML model trained with YOLOv8 on an image

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, yolo, yolov8

I developed a machine learning model to identify diseases in strawberries using the dataset [Strawberry Disease Detection Dataset(kaggle.com/datasets/usmanafzaal/strawberry-disease-detection-dataset). Below is the code I used to generate the model with YOLOv8:

```py
# Install necessary libraries
!pip install ultralytics
!pip install Roboflow

from IPython import display
display.clear_output()
import ultralytics
ultralytics.checks()
from ultralytics import YOLO
from IPython.display import display
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import albumentations as A
import cv2
import os
import shutil
from tqdm import tqdm
from roboflow import Roboflow

# Set up Roboflow
rf = Roboflow(api_key="5QjkWMTSB8bqpcDal2qp")
%cd ../
project = rf.workspace("dlbs-zcxsj").project("strawberry-hxgaj")
dataset = project.version(1).download("yolov8")

# Function to transform images
def transform_images(src_images_folder, dst_images_folder, src_labels_folder, dst_labels_folder, transforms):
    # Loop over all images
    for image_name in tqdm(os.listdir(src_images_folder)):
        # Load image
        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(src_images_folder, image_name))
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # albumentations uses RGB

        # Apply the augmentations
        transformed = transforms(image=image)
        transformed_image = transformed["image"]

        # Convert back to BGR for saving
        transformed_image = cv2.cvtColor(transformed_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # Save the augmented image
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dst_images_folder, image_name), transformed_image)

        # Copy the labels
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(src_labels_folder, image_name.replace('.jpg', '.txt')),
                    os.path.join(dst_labels_folder, image_name.replace('.jpg', '.txt')))

# Load YOLOv8 model
model = YOLO('yolov8s-seg.pt')

# Train the model
model.train(data=f"{dataset.location}/data.yaml", epochs=100, imgsz=512, name="base")
```

Now I have a file generated with the name "events.out.tfevents.1684793666.pop-os.340451.1" and let's say I want to take a photo of a strawberry in my field with the intention of testing it on my model and finding out If he has any of the model's reported illnesses, how could I do this through Google Colab?

I would like to test it because this ML model will be part of an application with ultralytcs and I would like to know some values ​​such as accuracy and cross-validation, I would like to obtain in addition to these values ​​something like the example below for strawberry images:

Something like this:

[image: Something like this]

Comment: Please focus your question. You say you want to a) ake a photo of a strawberry in my field with the intention of testing it on my model b) assess accuracy c) do cross validation which are different tasks and touch on different concepts. b) will entail to split your training data into three sets (train, test, validation) c) usually entails doing multiple different splits of your data and comparing the accuracy. a) will not really give you a good accuracy measure, unless you take many fotos and then check on how many your model makes the same prediction as you